# How to pass datatable as part of scenario outline example

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

I am using cucumber 4 with java

I have a scenario :-

```
Scenario: user views the address
  Given I login with user1
 Then I see all my house addresses
  |london|
Given I login with user2
Then I see all my house addresses
   |london|
   |spain|
   |brazil|
```

I want to convert it to scenario outline . How can I pass the addresses datatable as part of the Examples of scenario outline.

```
Scenario Outline: user views the address
 Given I login with <user>
 Then I see all my house addresses

Examples:
  |user |
  |user1|
  |user2|
```

The implementation of `I see all my house addresses` is (DataTable dataTable) and I want to keep it as datatable. Don't want to concatenate all addresses to a single string then I would miss the datatable.

```
Then("^I see all my house addresses$", (DataTable dataTable) -> {
  List<String> addresses = dataTable.asList(String.class);
});
```

Comment: Do the house addresses change for each user (I'm assuming they do)?

Comment: @greg This is the example. Objective is how to pass datatable as part of scenario outline.

Comment: The reason I ask about the expected number of addresses is because the number must be the same for each user. If the number of addresses will vary by user, a data table is not the right tool.

Comment: @greg say some other example where we need to pass data table. Like I go to class room of <classroom _number> and I see the following students. So again question remains the same ,Does cucumber allow such feature? if yes then how

Answer (score 3):

Cucumber allows you to pass data table arguments in scenario outlines. The syntax is exactly the same as a normal scenario, except the `<foo>` tokens used as placeholders for the values in each examples table row.

```
Scenario Outline: user views the address
  Given I login with <user>
  Then I see all my house addresses
    | <address 1> | # <-- "address 1" column in examples table
    | <address 2> | # <-- "address 2" column in examples table
    | <address 3> | # <-- "address 3" column in examples table

Examples:
  | user  | address 1 | address 2 | address 3 |
  | user1 | ...       | ...       | ...       |
  | user2 | ...       | ...       | ...       |
```

There is a tradeoff though. You cannot specify a different number of addresses for each user. You must specify the same number of addresses for each user. If `user1` shows London, Spain and Brazil, but `user2` only shows London and Spain, then a data table will not work for this use case.

Comment: That's the problem. Say one user having one address and another user having 100 addresses. First of all I have to create 100 columns . Secondly for user1 I have to pass the remaining 99 addresses as null or something like that and in the implementation step, I have to exclude those null values.

Comment: @asinha: Yes, you are correct. I do not believe data tables are the right tool for the job in this case.